# How do I create a new provisioning profile with entitlements?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

- I'm working on an app: `com.myco.foo`
- It uses "Associated Domains"
- I can't run the app on a physical iPhone due to this error:

`Failed to code sign "my app". None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.developer.associated-domains.`

How do I create a new provisioning profile to sign this?

When I try to create my own by doing the following:

- App ID's -> new (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle)
- id: 'com.myco.foo'
- enable associated domains
- Provisioning Profiles -> new (https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/)
- type: development
- select app id created above
- select my device
- finish creation
- download
- open (which opens Xcode but Xcode doesn't say anything about the profile that i opened)

I try to run on device, I get the error:

`An App ID with Identifier 'com.myco.foo' is not available.`

When I change the project app id to `com.myco.foo2`, I get the original error.

Comment: .p12 file can help you with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it needs to be a distribution type profile in order to run on a physical device: when creating the provisioning profile, you have to choose "Distribution: App Store". You don't select any devices during creation.

Answer (score 1):

First I would say regenerate all Development (or Distribution if you are trying to archive) provisioning profiles for your application.

Then, add the associated domain capability.

From the [Adding Capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html) section of Apple's App Distribution Guide:

> **To enable associated domains**
>
> 1. In the Capabilities pane, if Associated Domains isn’t enabled, click the switch in the Associated Domains section.
> 2. Click the Add button (+) at the bottom of the Domains table.
> 3. Double-click the placeholder text in the table, and enter the domain name you want to add.
>
> [image: Associated Domains]

Comment: I created provisioning profiles for my Notification Service Extension, I downloaded into my app. Everything is working. But when I added provisioning profiles, I didn't download any entitlements. Is that expected?

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all make sure you have added your `device udid` in provisioning profile you are using. If not added, add it from [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) and download latest provisioning profile, it resolves your issue.

2) If you have not created Development and Distribution code signing certificates on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) then ask relevant person for `.p12 certificates`.

Comment: Thanks! 1. My device is on my provisioning profile, but the app id is not, and wildcard doesn't work with associated domains. 2. Which .p12 certs do I ask for, and what do I do with them?

Comment: @Loren you need Development and Distribution certificates, install them and select them in Xcode from build settings.